# JTextPane - Where is the content?

Tags: java, swing, coding-style, save, jtextpane

So, I have a JTextPane

```
co_LoggerEdit = new JTextPane();
co_LoggerEdit.setContentType("text/html");
```

I then store the document & style thus:

```
co_LogDoc = co_LoggerEdit.getStyledDocument();
co_LogStyle = co_LoggerEdit.addStyle("style", null);
```

I then add text to the log with this routine:

```
StyleConstants.setForeground(co_LogStyle, col); // col == Color parameter
try { co_LogDoc.insertString(co_LogDoc.getLength(), text, co_LogStyle); }
catch (BadLocationException e) { System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage()); }
```

All this works fine, and on the screen I can see the log in its various colours and entries.

The problem comes when I want to save this data to file. I currently have this:

```
public void me_SaveLogToFile(String filename)
{
    StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument)co_LoggerEdit.getDocument();
    HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
    BufferedOutputStream out;

    try 
    {
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
        kit.write(out, doc, doc.getStartPosition().getOffset(), doc.getLength());
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        cLogger cl_Logger = cLogger.getInstance();
        cl_Logger.me_AddLog("ERROR: Save To File Failed", cLogger.LOG_TYPE.LOG_TYPE_ERROR, cLogger.LOG_LEVEL.LOG_LEVEL_NONE);
    }
}
```

And, whilst that does create a file, the contents of it only show the HTML styling, but not the actual content. Eg.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      <!--
        style { color: #000000 }
      -->
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p style="margin-top: 0">
      <font color="#808080"><style>
      </font><font color="#00ff00"><style>
      </font><font color="#000000"><style>
</font>    </p>
    <p style="margin-top: 0">
      <font color="#808080"><style>
      </font><font color="#ffffff"><style>
      </font><font color="#000000"><style>
</font>    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, what do I need to do to be able to access the actual content of the JTestPane, and not just the styling?

I also tried just using:

```
co_LoggerEdit.write(out)
```

through a Writer, but the outcome was the same.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do two things:

1. Save just the raw text, no style, to a plain text file.
2. Save the full content as html to keep colour etc, but with content in there!

So, what do I need to be looking at to find the actual content of the JTextPane? (with or without style)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `co_LoggerEdit.getText()` or

```
co_LoggerEdit.getDocument().getText(0, co_LoggerEdit.getDocument().getLength());
```

Comment: Your second bit allowed me to get the raw content of the log, many thanks. Is there a way to get full output? ie the html AND the content? Ie save a web-page of the log? (part 2 of the question?)

Comment: I think the co_LoggerEdit.getText() should return teh HTML with text. Not sure how it work with styles. Could you post a SSCCE to test?

Comment: SSCCE Here: http://www.sleeping-dragons.co.uk/Indy.zip
I've tried to boil down my code to the basics. The main form has three buttons to test the output of the three different routines I currently have.

Comment: It's not SSCCE. One of the S means "short". I would not like to run and go through all your project files. I need just a simple (less than 50 lines of code) example. Ideally one class to be posted here. so anybody here can take it and run.

Answer (score 1):

If I was on your shoes, I would make my own component containing a `JTextPane`, which stores the log's *plain* text and renders it with the corresponding colors. This would be the modular way.

Then, to save it, you only have to write the stored (raw) text to a file.

And, don't worry about saving the style, **the only important part of a log is the content**.
A log viewer can use different colors (among other things) to ease the view of the log's content.

Comment: co_LoggerEdit.getText() just returns the HTML of the styling, but the actual content of the log isn't listed. ie the result is the same as the HTML I listed above.

Comment: Mmmm, interesting. I never had problems with this. Reverting my answer to the other alternative.